# Ember-cli how to add FileSaverjs and Blobjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I looked at [this](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/02/05/generate-files-javascript-ember-js/) and [that](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/solved-using-file-saver-js-with-ember-cli/7457) link.  I bower installed file-saver and Blob.  I am having a similar problem with both components so I will just talk about one.

When I do `import FileSaver from 'file-saver';`

I get the following error.

```
Error while processing route: some.route Could not find module `file-saver` imported from `client/pods/some/folder/controller` Error: Could not find module `file-saver` imported from `client/pods/some/folder/controller`
```

I know the I have file-save because it is in my bower_components folder.

And right about the line that is giving me trouble is the following line.

`import Ember from 'ember';`

that package is about the file-saver package in my bower_components folder.  And the app seems to find that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower assets have to be imported in `Brocfile.js`, see http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies

In my project, filesaver is located at `bower_components/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js`, so I have the following line in my `Brocfile.js`:

`app.import('bower_components/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js');`

This makes it available as a global on `window.saveAs`, no need to use an import statement in the file you use it in.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  Also, where you have `app.import('bower_components/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js');` I think it should be `app.import('bower_components/file-saver/FileSaver.js');`  Not sure how your folder structure is set up, though.  If that is the way it is suppose to be, my apologies.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI—the difference in path depends on which fork of the repo that you install. `bower install FileSaver` installs a fork from the repo that installs if you use `bower install file-saver`. The latter seems to be the original repo, and is more recently maintained as of this post.